# Angular coffeescript syntax error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

Trying to convert working JS to coffee script in my angular app but its raises `Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'ContactController' is not a function, got undefined`

Here is my code.

```
angular.module("app", [
  "ngResource"
  "ngRoute"
]).run ($rootScope) ->

$rootScope.log = (thing) ->
console.log thing
```

The following js works fine

```
angular.module("app", ["ngResource", "ngRoute"]).run(function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.log = function(thing) {
    console.log(thing);
  };
});
```

Comment: Try using http://js2coffee.org/ to convert for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indents are off. Coffeescript is whitespace aware.

```
angular.module("app", [
  "ngResource"
  "ngRoute"
]).run ($rootScope) ->    
  $rootScope.log = (thing) ->
    console.log thing
```

Becomes:

```
angular.module("app", [ "ngResource", "ngRoute" ]).run ($rootScope) ->
  $rootScope.log = (thing) ->
    console.log thing
```

This doesn't explain why `ContactController` wouldn't be loading, but if your module isn't being defined correctly that could explain it.

Comment: same issue. Here is how I declare my controller `angular.module("app").controller "ProductsController", ($scope, $http) ->` It works fine with plain JS, bummer.

Comment: You'll want to get in the practice of named parameters for angular: `module.controller("personList", ["$scope", "toolsService", 'idService', ($scope, tools, idService) -> 

  ... etc
])
`. I don't think that's the issue here. Can you put this up on plnkr.co? That's the easiest way to troubleshoot angular issues.

Comment: I cheated and grabbed an existing template, but I adapted it to your code: http://plnkr.co/edit/AzCz8SDpL23qujrp5dQs?p=preview -- in the future you should get in the practice of putting things like logging into a service instead of putting them on the rootscope. I use a toolsService that has lodash and my app config, for instance.

Comment: can you take a look to this Plunker as well http://plnkr.co/edit/itYnyzg2uS5xc6MJIIkE?p=preview I don't understand why customers not showing with this factory

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/cYasZTgxixoKVaJWB429?p=preview -- short answer: you were attempting to pass a function into `factory.getCustomers` when getCustomers did not exist. From `factory.getCustomers ->` to `factory.getCustomers = -> `

Comment: Also, factories are good for returning an object. Services are good for doing things (sending data back to the server etc).

Comment: Thanks. I updated Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/0Vy2huEaoHDDZiSe9vh5?p=preview to introduce `$http`. The idea is sharing the api service for different actions, therefore only URL changes (should be passed as params) based on CRUD action. Really struggling with all those brackets

Comment: Looks like you're on the right track. There's a lot of ways to skin that cat, I'd read up on REST if I were you. Get, put, post and delete actions on your server. For instance, a POST to `/api/customer` would update an existing customer. And so on.

Comment: I'm familiar with REST and back-end stuff but any example how to pass url for each action (index, show) between the service and controller ? Thanks

Comment: You should be using separate controllers for list, edit, create etc views. Controllers are lightweight and should be small and specific. So if you have a CustomerEdit controller it will know what portion of the CustomerService to talk to.

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module("app", [
  "ngResource"
  "ngRoute"
]).run ($rootScope) ->
```

You missed a comma here..

```
angular.module("app", [
  "ngResource",
  "ngRoute"
]).run ($rootScope) ->
```

Comment: Nope, coffeescript will interpret same-level indents as separate items if they are in an array or function arg declaration. That compiles to: `angular.module("app", ["ngResource", "ngRoute"]).run(function($rootScope) {});`